# I got this error 'Failed to create Composer project:' in my first Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I create my first Laravel project via PhpStorm but when I write this command in PhpStorm's terminal `php artian serve` I got this error:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have one more problem too:

> Failed to create Composer project: Failed to run 'create-project' command

[image]

Comment: probably because you haven't properly setup composer in phpstorm.. have you tried creating a project in git bash or cmder or cmd?

Comment: just install `git` and `php` on your system, if they already exists on your system just add them to your `PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you system in not recognizing `php` and `git`, either they are not installed on your system of they are missed from the environment variable path for the system to recognize where they live.

In the seconds case do this to add path to your `PATH` variable:

> Right click My Computer, go to advanced settings, click Environment
>   Variables then edit the PATH system variable.
>
> Add a semi-colon and then the path to your PHP binary, i.e.
>   ";C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6"  and do the same for git.

Comment: I install git and add git and php in PATH now when I write the command php artisan serve I got warning:  PHP Warning:  require(D:\Laravel\First\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Lara
vel\First\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17 ,what is it?

Comment: I use this command 'composer update --no-scripts' and my problem solved thank you so much.

Comment: @sabasafavi You really don't want to rely on `--no-scripts`. Those scripts can be important, as can being able to run `php artisan`.